# "Second level cache for Entity Framework 6.1" plugin doesn't purge the cache when the entity changes

Tags: entity-framework, caching, lazy-loading

I'm using "Second level cache for Entity Framework 6.1", a Nuget plugin that refers to these websites for the documentation: 
https://blog.3d-logic.com/2014/03/20/second-level-cache-for-ef-6-1/
https://efcache.codeplex.com/

Entity Framework is on version 6.1.3, MVC is 5.2. We use the Code First approach and Lazy Loading.

I managed to make it work (queries are only fired the first time, then the data is fetched from the InMemoryCache), but the memory object doesn't reset when it or one of its dependencies are modified.

Did anyone try this plugin before? Have you experienced a similar behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be the fact that we were using Glimpse to check the performances. Once we removed Glimpse, it started working like a charm.

Comment: I find the plugin amazing Pawel, but I think it would be the case to look into this issue since I've read that more than one user is experiencing it. At the end of the day, when you are looking to measure performances probably the first tool you might want to install is exactly glimpse.